# Asynchronous WebService Approach (JAVA CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

I planning to create a JAVA asynchronous webservice using CXF.

This is my understanding so far:

In order to create async webservice via best practice, it need to be in such way:

Server:

1. create an messanging queue like ActiveMQ, grab the webservice request to put into an inbound queue and respond with an acknowledgement synchronously
2. process the inbound queue via listener on queue
3. send response message back to client (via long polling from client)

Client:

1. send request to server
2. received acknowledgement message
3. send long polling to server until it received response from server

How do I achieve it if I would like to use **Callback approach** instead of polling approach?

Please feel free to comment or feedback.

Comment: Besides, which Asynchronous Invocation Model approach (Polling or Callback) is better if the webservice server communicate with many clients at one time?

Comment: What do you mean by callback approach? Like if the client provided some URL then the server could post something to that URL when the job is done? Or could the client listen on a (JMS) queue?

Comment: Hi mekazu, I am referring to the http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/asynchronous-web-services-with-jboss-ws
It is implement on client side